# LIGHTTPD - How to set the vhost's permissions

Tags: lighttpd

I would like to run many VHOSTS with my lighttpd webserver.

I don't know how to chroot each vhost.

At the moment all the vhosts can read files owned by other vhosts, I don't think it's really sure!

Is there something you could advise?

At the moment for each vhost i create a new user, like:

```
website1.com:lighttpd
website2.com:lighttpd
website3.com:lighttpd
```

so different user with the same group (lighy run with lighttpd:lighttpd permissions)

Comment: Perhaps you can do it the other way around, create user and group website1, and make user lighttpd be part of each website group. That will make lighty be able to utilize the group permissions, but not the other website-users

Answer (score 1):

If `website1.com`, `website2.com`, ... and so on **are not** members of the `lighttpd` **group** and you set the permissions with `chown u+rwx,g+rX,g-w,o-rwx` (so files permissions will be `rwxr-----` and directories `rwxr-x---`) users of each vhost shouldn't be able to access, each other files.

Comment: so for you is better this implementation or ACL ? thank you so much!

Comment: @Damiano, well... ACL gives you more **fine grained** permissions... so in a way it's more flexible, and you can set more precisely **who can do what**, if your setup needs this kind of selection, that would be a better approach, if not, traditional unix permissions are well know and work fine.

Comment: thank you really much! I'm tring ACL, I think are good for my scope and as you told more flexible. I don't think it will touch the server performance, right?

Comment: @Damiano, you are welcome. As ACL is a more **complex system** is expected to have some **impact on performance**, a **quick search** took me to [this](http://www.suse.de/~agruen/acl/linux-acls/online/) where you can see some numbers on **Linux ACL performance**, anyway if you can the best is to run **your own benchmarks** and see the impact it has on **your setup**.